# how to pass a value to a hidden field using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<input type="hidden" id="name" name="hidden-new-field"/>
<form>
<input type="text" id="name-emails" />
<input id="send-btn" type="submit" class="button" value="SEND NOW" />
</form>
```

On button click I want to give the value of input type text to the value of hidden type

Answer (score 5):

There are few mistakes in your form

- there is no `name` attribute on **input type text**
- `id` of **Hidden** element should not be *name* (leading confusion)
- Hidden field should be inside `form` tag

i would prefer like this

#### PHP

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="email"  name="email"/>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_email" name="hidden_email"/>
<input type="submit" id="send_btn"  class="button" value="SEND NOW" />
</form>
```

#### jQuery

```
$("form").bind('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var formEmail=$("input[name=email]").val();
  $("input[type=hidden][name=hidden_email]").val(formEmail);     
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h97M6/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("#name").val("new_hidden_value");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input#send-btn').click(function(){
  $('input#name').val($('input#name-emails').val());
  return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = $("#name").val();
$("#name").val(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#send-btn').click(function() {
  $('#name').val($('#name-emails').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send-btn").click(function(){
        $("#name").val($("#name").val(name-emails)));
    });
});
```

Note that the above code will still submit the form afterwards, which I assume is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/h97M6/

```
$('form').bind('submit',function() {
    $('#name').val($('#name-emails').val())
    alert($('#name-emails').val())
    return false
})
```

Comment: I think it'd be better to use the `id`, in case he has more than one hidden input.